# Usage of the Dirichlet kernel in a trigonometric series proof

Tags: real-analysis, dirichlet-series

So in attempting to prove the pointwise convergent result $$\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N(f)(x) = f(x)$$ provided $$\exists \space \delta>0 \space \text{s.t.} \space |f(x+t) - f(x)| \leq C|t| \text{ for } |t| < \delta.$$

I'm seeing the following step taking place:

$$
\begin{multline}\left|\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) D_n(x-y)\, dy - f(x)\right|\\ = \left|\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) D_n(x-y) \,dy - f(x) \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} D_N(y)\,dy\right|.
\end{multline}$$

Is $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} D_N(y)\,dy = 1$, or how was this term added in?

Comment: It should be $f(y)$ on the first integral, but you are on the right track. Try rewrite the first integral as $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x-y)D_n(y)dy$ and see what happens.

Comment: @CheeHan sorry if I wasn't clear here, but I have the proof finished and everything past this step makes perfect sense. However, I'm not sure how to justify this step.

Comment: OHHHH, missed that. That was purely because $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} D_N(y)\, dy =1$.

Comment: @CheeHan got it, thank you!